# How to add additional class to the component list view html

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, event-system, sites-9.1

I have to add additional class to the component list view html if the approval status is expired to highlight with different color in the GUI.

Please suggest the better approach to acheive this.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for more details - https://docs.sdl.com/783502/696275/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/gui-extensions

Comment: Also check this link - https://docs.sdl.com/792468/277950/sdl-web-8--retired-/data-extender-example-adding-a-new-column-to-a-list-view

Comment: @Anand NS - I have gone through this documentation but I wanted to know the specific approach to add a class like the selected class is getting added when the item is selected and it is grayed out so how can I pass a class like "Expired" from back end to the front end?